# How to give Json schema file to spark 1.6 to load schema to spark DataFrame

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

Hi I'm Trying to load CSV file to spark dataframe. I'm using DataBricks CSV jar to load the data. I have data schema in a Json file and want to apply that schema to the DataFrame.

Below is My Json Schema File:-

```
 {
  "type" : "struct",
  "doc": "This is sample",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "Name",
    "type" : "string" ,
    "nullable" : "true" 
  }, {
    "name" : "Address1",
    "type" : "string",
    "nullable" : "true" 
  }, {
    "name" : "Address2",
    "type" : "string",
    "nullable" : "true" 
  }, {
    "name" : "City",
    "type" : "string",
    "nullable" : "true" 
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code may helpful for you.

```
StructType tempSchema = new StructType(new StructField[]{
            new StructField("name", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty()),
            new StructField("Address1", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty()),
            new StructField("Address2", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty()),
            new StructField("City", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty())
        });

    Dataset<Row> resultDs = spark.createDataFrame(dataRows, tempSchema);
```

Comment: Thanks, Srinu... currently i'm using this way to give schema to dataframe. What i am asking, if it is possible that spark can automatically read the schema file and get the schema from that schema file.

Comment: okay Himanshu, Please check this may helpful for you 
https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro

Comment: Thanks. Srinu.. The input data i'm using is in CSV format and i think the above link is for avro data file. I'm using Spark 1.6